# Synchronous changing and moving UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I'm doing at the same time

```
CGRect centView = rootview.frame;
centView.origin.x = rootview.frame.origin.x;
centView.origin.y =   your_float;
centView.size.height = screenHeight - (your_float * 2);
rootview.frame = centView;
```

and

```
CGRect frame = myview.frame;
frame.origin.x = myview.frame.origin.x;
frame.origin.y =   20 - shift - 3;
myview.frame = frame;
```

and

myview is be in rootview then myview not moving and moving jerkily. How do they work together?

Comment: Eeee... What ? What are you trying to do here.

Comment: I'm changing the value of centView.origin.y, centView.size.height, frame.origin.y. The call comes on the movement of the mouse.

Comment: Did you try to NSLog the function which is not working to see if that really happens ? Or put a breakpoint there ?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time?" Is there an animation involved? What does it mean to be "not moving and moving jerkily." Is it moving or is it not moving? My strong hunch is that you're probably assigning this stuff on a background queue, but it's extremely hard to tell from your question.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(msgResponder:) name:@"leftPanelMsg" object:nil];
    }

Comment: -(void)msgResponder:(NSNotification *)notification {  
       float f = [notification.object floatValue];
       [self move: f];
    }

Comment: -(void)move: (CGFloat) your_float {
       CGRect centView = rootview.frame;
       centView.origin.x = rootview.frame.origin.x;
       centView.origin.y =   your_float;
       centView.size.height = screenHeight - (your_float * 2);
       rootview.frame = centView;

       CGRect frame = myview.frame;
       frame.origin.x = myview.frame.origin.x;
       frame.origin.y =   20 - your_float - 3;
       myview.frame = frame;
    
    }